# CentOS 7 “Invalid user __ from xx.xx.xx.xx port xxx” - Not showing the attempted username entered

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, login

When taking a look into my /var/log/secure logging file, I'm able to see attempts to log into my CentOS system via SSH, however, the username is blank. I've recreated this myself by entering false usernames, but the log still shows it being blank.

```
Feb 11 15:40:02 centos sshd[15369]: Invalid user  from xxx.181.90.221 port 51474
Feb 11 15:40:48 centos sshd[15394]: Invalid user  from xxx.181.90.221 port 51514
Feb 11 15:40:57 centos sshd[15396]: Invalid user  from xxx.181.90.221 port 51526
Feb 11 15:49:15 centos sshd[15462]: Invalid user  from xxx.181.90.221 port 51933
Feb 11 15:49:24 centos sshd[15464]: Invalid user  from xxx.181.90.221 port 51941
Feb 11 15:49:31 centos sshd[15466]: Invalid user  from xxx.181.90.221 port 51948
Feb 11 15:58:55 centos sshd[15622]: Invalid user  from xxx.181.90.221 port 52415
Feb 11 15:59:02 centos sshd[15624]: Invalid user  from xxx.181.90.221 port 52422
Feb 11 15:59:08 centos sshd[15626]: Invalid user  from xxx.181.90.221 port 52427
Feb 11 16:05:13 centos sshd[15684]: Invalid user  from xxx.181.90.221 port 52723
Feb 11 16:05:37 centos sshd[15688]: Invalid user  from xxx.181.90.221 port 52741
Feb 11 16:15:10 centos sshd[15776]: Invalid user  from xxx.181.90.221 port 53203
Feb 11 16:19:23 centos sshd[3862]: Invalid user  from xxx.181.90.221 port 53410
```

Any idea on how I could get this to provided the attempted username? This seemed to start happening after I set up Fail2Ban.

Thanks!

EDIT: It looks as though it will only log the usernames that are attempted from an internal IP address. Any external IP address will not log the username. Here is an external address trying to connect:

```
Feb 11 16:19:23 centos sshd[3862]: Invalid user  from xxx.181.90.221 port 53410
```

and here it is from an internal IP:

```
Feb 11 19:12:33 centos sshd[4193]: Invalid user badusername from 192.168.1.10 port 1718
```

Comment: `fail2ban` doesn't alter any of the logging processes. It simply reads the logs that get generated. If the format really did change then something else is responsible. (Do you have any evidence to confirm that the log file used to include the username?)

Comment: Yes, earlier before I installed fail2ban and set the ssh logpath as /var/log/secure, it logged user names.

`Feb 11 12:39:54 centos sshd[15331]: Invalid user admin from xx.xx.xx.xx port 51285`

Comment: It also looks as though if I connect to my centos box from the internal IP address it will log the username, but if its an external IP address it will not log the username.

Comment: Sure! I went ahead and made the edits. I'm going to do another restart of the CentOS machine and see if that may fix anything.

Comment: The username used could actually have been empty or a space or tab, possibly in an attempt to confuse or bypass security (which didn't work on your system obviously).

Comment: Interesting, I would've thought it'd show a null or something - bad of me to assume! I'll try hitting it from an external address and not type a username, then do it again with a faulty username and see what happens.

Comment: Ah. You have fixed the formatting, and the double space where the username might be placed is now apparent. (Earlier, on my mobile, there was definitely only a single space shown there.) I'd concur with @Kusalananda that someone's probing your machine with a null or empty username.

Comment: Giving it a shot now - I will report back! Also shout-out to whoever it was that fixed my formatting, I appreciate it! (As you can tell I'm a new poster to these forums)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fail2ban` itself doesn't alter any of the logging processes. It simply reads the logs that get generated. However, I can reproduce the issue as described by specifying a null username:

```
ssh -l '' remote_host
```

The corresponding log entries in `/var/log/auth.log` on my Debian server are

```
Feb 12 16:35:43 remote_host sshd[6738]: Invalid user  from 192.168.xx.yy port 26677
Feb 12 16:35:43 remote_host sshd[6738]: input_userauth_request: invalid user  [preauth]
```

Looking closely you can see the double space between `user` and `from` in that first line, as seen in your own logs.

Comment: I was able to get around to my testing. It looks like I'm able to log the username attempts now from both internal and external IP addresses. I'm guessing the username being entered in was just a space or empty as @Kusalananda suggested. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Based on my testing, if the username had been a space you'd have got three adjacent spaces in the log message.